# Control browser type

Tags: c#, asp.net

In .aspx page, I want to control the browser type and if it is IE 6 , I want to show a message.

How can I do it?

Comment: What do you mean by "control the browser type"?

Comment: check this out..http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/WebBrowser.aspx

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to determine Browser type from Server side using ASP.NET & C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2311077/how-to-determine-browser-type-from-server-side-using-asp-net-c)

Comment: try out this, it will get you the data you need about your browser
    System.Web.HttpBrowserCapabilities browser = Request.Browser;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[How to: Detect Browser Types and Browser Capabilities in ASP.NET Web Pages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3yekbd5b.aspx)

I'm not certain on the output for IE6, but you could do something like:

```
if (browser.Browser == "IE" && browser.Type == "6"){
   phMessage.visible = True;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This should be approached by using [conditional comments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

```
<body>
    ....
    <!--[if lte IE 6]>
        <div class="bigAndBold">YOUR BROWSER SUCKS</div>
    <![endif]-->
    ....
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<%
    var b = Request.UserAgent.ToString();
    if (b.Contains("MSIE 6.0"))
    {
        Response.Write("IE 6!"); 

    }

// Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0) == IE 9
// Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:6.0.2) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/6.0.2  == FF6 

    %>
```